# JMeter sample response encoding

Tags: java, testing, encoding, jmeter

I'm having problems with JMeter's handling of unicode characters. When a sample response contains such characters, they are returned corrupted.
For example, I'm using the dummy sampler with this response data:

```
Hauptschule Sankt Pýlten, Pottenbrunn
```

And JMeter returns:

```
Hauptschule Sankt P�lten, Pottenbrunn
```

I've set these properties in saveservice.properties and jmeter.properties respectively:

```
_file_encoding=UTF-8
sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8
```

but it makes no difference.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Right property to set / change in *jmeter.properties* is

```
 sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8
```

(if omitted default is ISO-8859-1)

Answer (score 9):

Add a BSF post processing element to the sampler with the following script:

```
prev.setDataEncoding("UTF-8")
```

That's what worked for me.

Comment: Just as a note: The BSF post processing is deprecated for some time and will be removed in 3.3 AFAIK. But of course this also works fine with a JSR223 PostProcessor when selecting either one of the beanshell or javascript languages.

Comment: Successfully used this syntax in a JSR223 PostProcessor using JMeter 5.4.1